# Explanation of the solution in "Finding common value of two sequences" question.

Tags: sequences-and-series

In [Finding common value of two sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743790/finding-common-value-of-two-sequencees) given:

> $m^2 + 928m + 687: 1616, 2547, 3480, 4415, 5352, \dots$
>
> and
>
> $n^2 + 54n + 729: 784, 841, 900, 961, 1024, \dots$?

The [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1743801/484522) is:

> $$m^2+928m+687 = n^2+54n+729 \\ (m+464)^2-(n+27)^2 = 464^2-687 \\
>  (m+n+491)(m-n+437) = 214609 = 317*677 = 1*214609\\ \cases{m=33, n=153
>  \\ m=106841, n=107277}$$

How the values $m$ and $n$ were found after the factorization of the number $214609$ ?

Comment: solve the system $m+n+491=677$ and $m-n+437=317$ or the system $m+n+491=214609$ and $m-n+437=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by solving the system $\cases{m+n+491=677\\ m-n+437=317}$ and the system $\cases{m+n+491=214609\\m-n+437=1}$